# How to correctly detect accessing wp-content/uploads?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, hooks, pdf, template-redirect

Not sure if this is a stupid question or not; however, I've been trying to detect when a user accesses a PDF. I want to be able to know how often a user is accessing specific PDF files. I have been playing around with the 'template_redirect' hook, but the below code doesn't seem to be functioning.

```
function detect_access() {
            $server_request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

            if ( strpos($server_request, '/wp-content/uploads') !== false ) {
                wp_redirect( home_url('/') );
                exit;
            }
        }
```

I would really appreciate the help, is there a hook that deals with this issue/another solution I have been blind to? Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress does not serve those files, when you request a PDF it's Apache/Nginx that serves the file to the browser, no PHP is executed. This is a good thing as it's much faster than PHP and saves a lot of server resources.

For this reason, your attempt won't work, and no changes to the PHP will fix it.

> I want to be able to know how often a user is accessing specific PDF files.

If you want to track views then you have these options:

- embed the PDF in a page that you can track
- put the PDF behind a paywall or button that you can track that redirects to the PDF

Note that browsers will cache the PDF, and that most browsers will provide download options when displaying PDFs. For this reason your stats will be unreliable. You may not be able to get the results you want out of an uploaded PDF.

Also, if someone shares a direct URL to the PDF it will not trigger any tracking.

The only other option, is to never share the URL to the PDF at all, and instead use a custom URL that retrieves and displays the URL using server headers. However this too can be saved by the browser, and can be cached ( or even printed to a new untraced PDF via the system print dialog ). It will also be slower and use much more server resources for minimal gain.

Comment: huh, that explains a lot... thanks for the reply.

Comment: if you're doing this as part of a marketing or ecommerce solution I'd suggest using on of the existing solutions out there instead of rolling your own, but there's no foolproof solution. E.g. in the past I've bought workouts that are PDFs and that came as a passworded PDF with an email that had the link plus the password, but once i had it I could do what I liked. Another had no password but the link sent in email expired after 24 hours so it could only be used once. Again though nothing stopped me downloading and copying the PDF, passwords can be stripped out, and "print as PDF" is trivial

Comment: you mentioned using a button that redirects to the pdf, was the a simple way to detect certain buttons being pressed?

Comment: you would need to implement that via PHP, but again it's not going to be reliable, I would not trust any stats you get out of this. Here, you would implement it by just having a button or link that when clicked redirects somewhere, and while it's redirecting the PHP would also do whatever analytics code you've decided to use. It's not a sophisticated thing to do, literally just a link to your site that when clicked redirects, maybe because there's a URL parameter added. Again, it's going to give poor results, it will not be reliable, you will have issues, it is not the solution you are hoping

Comment: fundamentally, what you want to do is not possible in any meaningful or accurate manner. It is similar to trying to stop people from stealing your images by disabling right click, people can still drag and drop, screenshot, save the page and extract the file, open dev tools, disable JS, etc etc. Instead if you're trying to determine how many times _content_ is accessed, that is actually possible, extract the content from the PDF and put it on a page in HTML, then standard analytics solves the problem trivially